# Hbase query performance

Tags: hbase

We have hasbe table with rowkey as user id + timestamp. Around 70% of our usecases use user id as part of scan. But other 30% scenarios does not depend on user id. It's like fetch all users who had done changes between this time. Currently we are storing the timestamp as column and using Columnvaluefilter to get the results. Is there a way better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arul.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding start and stop timestamps to Scan, if you write timestamp to table yourself, not default hbase timestampig.

I would suggest another filter if you know exact dates, or date+hours to search between and this date range is relatively small. FuzzyRowFilter, can be used, but unfortunately it does not have a range pattern, so when i use it to search for dates, since my rowkey has yyyyMMddHH pattern in it, i can add a fuzzy filter for every hour in range to Scan object, but this is not good for if you end up with 10s of filters. But if you have time you can try, because now using column value filter means, full table scan for every query.

You can read this task to learn about range supporting fuzzy row filter. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6618 It is open for years and does have a patch.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario rowkey contains timestamp in milliseconds and due to this fuzzy row filter could not be used. But the input was useful and i can try that in other usecases where the rowkey contains date. In my use case data was fetched and displayed in a html table with paging logic. I exactly know what users for which this data needs to retrieved from Hbase. Given this, i had went ahead and implemented Range Filter and it worked out well. Please find the code below.

```
List<RowRange> ranges = new ArrayList<RowRange>();
                for(String user: users){
                    String startRowKey = user + HbaseConstants.ROW_KEY_SEPERATOR + startTimeStamp;
                    String endRowKey = user + HbaseConstants.ROW_KEY_SEPERATOR +endTimeStamp;
                    ranges.add(new RowRange(Bytes.toBytes(startRowKey), true, Bytes.toBytes(endRowKey), false));
                }

                MultiRowRangeFilter rangeFilter = new MultiRowRangeFilter(ranges);

                FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
                filterList.addFilter(rangeFilter);
                scan.setFilter(filterList);
```